# iOS app crashed while loading ad?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, admob

Here is my code in `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.bannerView_= [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80,
                                                self.view.frame.size.height -
                                                GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,
                                                GAD_SIZE_320x50.width, 
                                                GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)]; 

self.bannerView_.adUnitID = @"a15037256bd8776";
self.bannerView_.rootViewController =self;
[self.view addSubview:self.bannerView_];
[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

My app is designed for landscap mode only. And it works fine in home screen, but when i goes to other screens and trying to load ad(by clicking on banner) the ad is loaded in half part of screen, other half part of screen remains unchanged.
Can anybody help me please.

Comment: I added that code(posted in my question) in viewDidLoad method of all the views, but works fine for home screen only?

Comment: Can anybody help me please? i spent my whole day to resolve this issue.

Comment: How is the ad still showing if you're going to another screen? Are you moving the bannerView but not updating its rootViewController possibly?

Comment: @RajPara the above code is added in viewDidLoad method of all the views, so i get Ad in the screens.Can you provide me some sample code that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more then two days finally i resolved the issue-

Instead to instantiate and call GADBannerView from viewDidLoad of all my view's, I've created a singleton class and use it. [see this link for more help](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2012/04/creating-gadbannerview-singleton-in.html)

Answer (score 1):

try following code

```
self.adBanner= [[GADBannerView alloc]
                    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                             self.view.frame.size.height -
                                             GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,
                                             GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                             GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];

    self.adBanner.adUnitID = @"a15037256bd8776";
    self.adBanner.delegate = self;
    self.adBanner.rootViewController =self; 
    [self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];

    [self.adBanner loadRequest:[self createRequest]];
```

Comment: i tried your answer but it give me same result, ad stil loaded in half screen.

Comment: above one is for Portrait  mode.